# Capture a part of screen takes time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, core-graphics

I am using this code to capture the part of `iPad` screen.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(500, 500, 600, 600);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([viewImage CGImage], 
rect);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil); 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

But this is very slow in comparison to capture part of screen starting from {0,0} to {100,100} using the code

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[yourView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The difference between them is the rect size passes to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext. Can we capture CGRectMake(500, 500, 600, 600) without passing complete screen bounds to GraphicContext?
Please write code too.

Comment: As a suggestion, have you tried to let this process to be done on another queue rather that the UI (main) one?

Comment: No. Since i am updating UI in each for loop and capture again, i dont think transferring to other thread will work. Although i didnt try, i am guessing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can capture just a smaller part of the view. Create the context at size 600x600, then translate the origin of the context to 500,500 before asking the layer to render.

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(500, 500, 600, 600);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y);
[yourView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

You might also want to look at the `-[UIView drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:]` method. [According to WWDC 2013 Session 226, “Implementing Engaging UI on iOS”](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/226/), `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` is significantly faster than `renderInContext:`. See slide 41 for a speed comparison: 844 ms for the older method, and 145 ms for the newer method in their example.